# Is lua table thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, lua

Say, I have a lua table `t={"a"={}, "b"={}}`.

My question is, I have two threads, thread A, thread B.
And if I create two lua_State individually for these two threads through lua_newthread, and thread A only read/write `t.a`, thread B only read/write `t.b`.

Should I use lua_lock in each thread above?

If the answer is YES, then, does any of operation on `t` need a lua_lock?

Comment: I suggest read about what `lua_newthread` does.

Comment: Answer is "YES": you should use `lua_lock` in each thread above.

Comment: Answers go under Your Answer header on the page ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, lua table is not thread safe.

And yes, all operation on table `t` will need `lua_lock`, because none of them is atomic operation.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: A Lua engine-state is not thread-safe, so there's no reason to make the Lua table thread-safe.

A `lua_State` is not the engine state, though it references it. Instead, it is the state of a Lua thread, which is no relation to an application thread. Lua threads with the same engine state cannot execute concurrently, as the Lua engine is inherently single-threaded (you may use an arbitrary number of engines at the same time though), instead they are cooperatively multitasked.

So [`lua_State *lua_newthread (lua_State *L);`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#lua_newthread) creates a new Lua thread, not an OS thread.

`lua_lock` and the like do not refer to thread safety, but were the way native code can keep hold of Lua objects across calls into the engine in version 2 of the implementation: https://www.lua.org/manual/2.1/subsection3_5_6.html
The modern way is using the registry, a Lua table accessible from native code: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.5

Answer (score 0):

lua table isn't thread safe, but there's no need to lock since threads don't read/write on the same element.

Comment: But they belong to the same table `t`